# sorting php array in case it exsit in other array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$a= [ '1' => ['key'=>'1','id'=>'4' ],
      '2' => ['key'=>'2','id'=>'1' ],
      '3' => ['key'=>'3','id'=>'5' ]
    ]

$b = [1,5]
```

so i want to sort array `$a` so that if `$a[*]['id']` is in `$b` array it should be first.

so in this example the out put should be

```
$a = ['2' => ['key'=>'2','id'=>'1' ],
      '3' => ['key'=>'3','id'=>'5' ]
      '1' => ['key'=>'1','id'=>'4' ],
    ]
```

i tried

```
uasort($a, function($k, $v) use ($b) {
        return in_array($v['id'],$b) ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

yet failed :(

is there an optimum method for doing such a trick using any of the php sorting functions?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`uasort()`](http://us2.php.net/uasort)?

Comment: yp, yet didnt know how to dive to reach 'id' value to compare it in the call back function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uasort($a, function ($x, $y) use ($b) {
    return !in_array($x['id'], $b);
});
```

You must note that `$y` is not used and the code will work without referencing it, but I prefer this way for completeness.

X and Y are any two array values. If the sort function returns 1, X is placed last (first Y, last X). If returns -1, X go first (first X, last Y).

In this case, the sort function will return `true` (equivalent to 1) if `$x[id]` is not in `$b`, so the order will be first Y, then X. This sort will move to the last positions all the array values whith `id` not in `$b`.

After say that, you can also use this code without `$y`:

```
uasort($a, function ($x) use ($b) {
    return !in_array($x['id'], $b);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain to me what are the variables that uasort pass to the function ? i mean what is $y ?

Comment: @Edakos I answered but I feel you have the efficient one so one up from my end :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation

```
$a= array( '1' => array('key'=>'1','id'=>'4' ), '2' => array('key'=>'2','id'=>'1' ), '3' => array('key'=>'3','id'=>'5' ) );
$b = array(1,5);
asort($a); 
function customuksort($t1, $t2) {
    global $a;

    return $a[$t1] < $a[$t2] ? -1 : 1;
}
uksort($b, 'customuksort');

print_r($a);
```

The output is

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [key] => 1 [id] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [key] => 2 [id] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [key] => 3 [id] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: Follow the answer from @Edakos he has better solution.